# Drupal 7 Field API hook_field_validate not receiving data?

Tags: drupal-7

My module implements a range of the field api functions in order to provide a custom field type consisting of a text field and a textarea. The hook_field_validate function gets called with all the correct keys but never any values - would really appreciate it if someone would take a look over all the code and tell me if there are any problems.

```
function brooklands_field_info() {
    return array(
        'brooklands_heading_text' => array(
            'label' => t('Heading with text'),
            'description' => t('Heading with text - says it all.'),
            'default_widget' => 'brooklands_heading_text_widget',
            'default_formatter' => 'brooklands_heading_text_formatter',
        ),
    );
}

function brooklands_field_validate($entity_type, $entity, $field, 
                        $instance, $langcode, $items, &$errors) {
    /*foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {

            // $item never contains any data!!!!!

        $heading = check_plain($item['brooklandsheading']);
        $text = check_markup($item['value'], $item['format']);
        if(!empty($heading) || !empty($text) && empty($heading) || empty($text)) {
            $errors[$field['field_name']][$langcode][$delta][] = array(
                'error' => 'brooklands_invalid',
            'message' => t('Must have both heading and text'),
        );
        }
    }*/
}

function brooklands_field_widget_error($element, $error, $form, &$form_state) {
    switch ($error['error']) {
        case 'brooklands_invalid':
        form_error($element, $error['message']);
        break;
    }
}

function brooklands_field_is_empty($item, $field) {
    return empty($item['brooklandsheading']) || empty($item['value']);
}

function brooklands_field_formatter_info() {
    return array(
        'brooklands_heading_text_formatter' => array(
            'label' => t('Heading text formatter'),
            'field types' => array('brooklands_heading_text'),
        ),
    );
}

function brooklands_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, 
                        $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
    $element = array();
    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
        $element[$delta]['#markup'] = '<div class="brooklands-heading-text"><h3>'
        .check_plain($item['brooklandsheading']).'</h3>'
        .check_markup($item['value'], $item['format']).'</div>';
    }
    return $element;
}

function brooklands_field_widget_info() {
    return array(
        'brooklands_heading_text_widget' => array(
            'label' => 'Heading/text widget',
            'field types' => array('brooklands_heading_text'),
        ),
    );
}

function brooklands_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, 
                        $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
    $element['brooklandsheading'] = array(
        '#delta' => $delta,
        '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['brooklandsheading']) ? 
            $items[$delta]['brooklandsheading'] : '',
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#size' => 64,
        '#maxlength' => 256,
        '#title' => t('Heading')
    );
    $text = array(
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['value']) ? 
            $items[$delta]['value'] : '',
    );
    $element += $text;
    $element['#format'] = isset($items[$delta]['format']) ? 
                            $items[$delta]['format'] : NULL;
    $element['#base_type'] = $element['#type'];
    $element['#type'] = 'text_format';
    $element['#title'] = t('Text');
    return $element;
}
```

EDIT: This is the hook_field_schema implementation from my module's install file-

```
function brooklands_field_schema($field) {
    $columns = array(
        'brooklandsheading' => array(
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'length' => 256,
            'not null' => FALSE
        ),
        'value' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'not null' => FALSE
        ),
        'format' => array(
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'length' => 255,
            'not null' => FALSE,
        ),
    );
    return array(
        'columns' => $columns,
        'indexes' => array(
            'format' => array('format'),
        ),
        'foreign keys' => array(
            'format' => array(
                'table' => 'filter_format',
                'columns' => array('format' => 'format'),
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this code a little confusing and I'm no expert, but I've just grappled with and fixed a similar problem and I feel this question deserves at least a cautious partial answer for the record.

I understand it, the form generates by looping through and rendering the $element array, and it figures out how to match the resulting input to the schema by the keys of each item in the array.

So, the thing that immediately looks wrong to me here is, that the schema sets up 3 types of data to store: 'brooklandsheading', 'value', and 'format', so I'd expect the $element array to have $element['brooklandsheading'] which defines the text field, $element['value'] which defines the text area, and $element['format'] which defines another text field.

(Confusing names, by the way! Personally I'd avoid using 'value' and 'format', to avoid confusion with ['#value'] and formatters)

What looks like a problem with this code is that it is slotting the form which should be mapping onto ['value'] right onto $element without a ['value'] key. I can't see how the form would know which column to feed it through to.

I don't really know what's going on with ['#format'] to be honest, it doesn't look right but I can't figure out what it's trying to do.

So for this code, I'd immediately suggest replacing `$text = array( '#type' => 'textarea', ...` with `$element['value'] = array( ' '#type' => 'textarea',`

As for why $element['brooklandsheading'] isn't passing through, nothing jumps out as wrong in the code, so my suspicion is it might be because of another little 'gotcha': After changing the schema in hook__field_schema(), you have to **delete** all instances of the field, then **disable** and then completely **uninstall** the module from the Modules -> Uninstall tab, then re-enable the module and re-create all the fields. To apply the changed schema, Drupal needs to drop and recreate tables from your database, and Drupal won't do that unless it's sure it's not going to destroy valuable data.